# JavaScript forEach does not fully iterate over indices when remove an index

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, which I am iterating over, and trying to remove a specific object from the list.

Running over the array I remove the first index and iterates only 2 times instead of 3 times.

```
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'test1'
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'test2'
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'test1'
}]

data.forEach((item: any, index:any) => { 
  if (item.name === 'test1') { 
    data.splice(index, 1); // Remove one record then and it stops early
  }
});
```

Does anyone help me that iterate the fully if removed anything during the iteration?

Comment: use filter function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're removing an index from the array while traversing the array.  So the array that you're working on is being altered on each iteration.

Since you've removed index 0 from the array the length is now 2 so it stops on the second iteration.

Instead of using `forEach` use `filter` (see [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cgh8ez?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) for example), which doesn't mutate the original array and returns the new array, which you could then reassign.

```
let data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'test1'
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'test2'
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'test1'
}];

console.log('BEFORE', data); // Original data

data = data.filter((item: any, index: any) => item.name !== 'test1');

console.log('AFTER', data); // Only `test2` remains now
```